# How to use biometric fingerprint reader to develop a fingerprint database

Tags: authentication, fingerprint, image-scanner

I have purchased a simple biometric fingerprint reader that is usually used for laptop security through a USB connection. It is just called biomentric finger print reader, not branded! It came with the software for creating security for laptop, and it works great.

However, I had a different idea for it: I am intending to create a database of users fingerprints so that I can identify which user swiped their fingers on it, ie, to use it for **different users' authentication using fingerprints**. I don't seem to be making any head or tail on how to go about that.

I would like to find out if there is other kind of software to install that will make this gadget print the fingerprint or a code to say a spreadsheet or database whenever I swipe a finger on it? I was thinking it would be a simple as when I use a bar code scanner to print codes of various items to a spreadsheet.

Could someone please advise how to go about this. I believe it should do that but I just dont know where to start.

thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me which device you bought and if it is compatible with WBF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WBF (Windows biometric Framework) API that is free, but you must first verify if your biometric device is WBF compatible. The documentation and samples for WBF are for C++, but there is a wrapper sample in C# that you can download here:  [Cirrostrata biometrics](https://code.google.com/p/cirrostrata-biometrics/) Regarding how to convert the scanned data into an image, you can check this post: [How to convert winbio data into image](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6f09403-e0b6-4977-b697-d5aabeb5b8ff/how-to-convert-winbiobir-data-into-image-using-windows-biometric-framework). Hope this helps to start.

Comment: Thank you for this. This has lead me to the SDK which I have downloaded. However, I can't find any example of how to write any code with it. I have imported the dll into my project but I can figure out what to do with it after that

Comment: You can download a sample of the implementation here: https://code.google.com/p/cirrostrata-biometrics/source/browse/

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I however think my fingerprint reader is some weird brand, it is not being detected by the sample application! It came with its login software called BioExcess. So anytime I swipe a finger it only starts running that software!

Comment: Maybe it is the same sensor that I have, the Es603 that comes with the Bioexcess software. To make it work, you have to install the native drivers for Windows. This link shows how to do it: http://superuser.com/questions/746778/win8-1-how-to-get-fingerprint-sensor-egistec-es603-to-work

Comment: Thank you so much, @Tito! The sample application is now detecting the swiped finger! It currently reports to me Failed in the Status textbox. I now just need to figure out how to re-write the sample so that I can store several fingerprints and authenticate them. All I need to do this for is to store in a database what time an existing fingerprint was swiped. Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: This post shows how to enroll in C++. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401619(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks again. you are very helpful! I must admit, though, that I have never understood any C++ code. I tried converters and I just got errors. But I am willing to learn if this could help me because I am under a lot of pressure. I have been looking for any sample of this code in C#/VB but still kind find anything. I would really appreciate some help with that last bit, kindly :)

Comment: I have also created this as a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433167/wrapper-for-winbiocapture-sample-with-callback-function) since I think it can stand on its own

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative wrapper to WinBioNET as mentioned by Robinicks there is [WinBiometric.Net](https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/WinBiometricDotNet).

**Disclaimer: I do not own this project.**

It has a really nice test project for playing around with the different API functions available in the Windows Wiometric Framework.  This test project was monumental in helping me understand the Windows Biometric Framework.

[image: Windows Biometric Framework Tester]

The WinBiometric.Net wrapper has a claim of 100% API coverage, a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinBiometricDotNet) and has the [MIT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).

I found it to generally have a very high quality of code as well.

As for storing the fingerprints in a database you could use the `WinBioCaptureSample` [API function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbiocapturesample) to capture a sample, which can then be stored in a database.
The sample can be converted into an image as well, there is a nice example of this in the wrapper.

I know this is an old question but I figured I'd post anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WinBioNET](https://github.com/JcBernack/WinBioNET) .NET wrapper for Windows Biometric Framework (WBF). It has a demo winforms app in the solution. Just open it up, select the demo app as the "startup project" and run. If you have any devices connected it will enumerate it at startup.

Comment: Harsh Gupta, would you be planning to do a JNI JAVA  wrapper for the same?

Comment: Its not my library, dude!