# use finger print sensor as bio metric

Tags: android, sensors, using, fingerprint

I am new to android bio-metric integration.

Is it possible to use the android devices screen or fingerprint sensor as a biometric device so that users can login into the app without having to use any email or password.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276026/using-androids-fingerprint-scanner-for-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468694/android-fingerprint-api-for-time-attendance-app/33473549#33473549) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/604029/Fingerprintplusscannerpluscodeplusforplusandroidpl) as references.

Is using an external fingerprint scanner or biometric the only option or is there an alternative solution ?

This is the code that I've used as a reference. Please have a look at it and let me know how can I get users fingerprint.

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FingerprintManager fingerprintManager;
private KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
private KeyStore keyStore;
private KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
private static final String KEY_NAME = "example_key";
private Cipher cipher;
private FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    keyguardManager =
            (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    fingerprintManager =
            (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);


    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Lock screen security not enabled in Settings",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return;
    }

    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

        // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Register at least one fingerprint in Settings",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

        // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Register at least one fingerprint in Settings",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    generateKey();

    if (cipherInit()) {
        cryptoObject =
                new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
        FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
        helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
    }

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
protected void generateKey() {
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
                "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException
            | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @mohammed. Wellcome to stackoverflow. You should provide some part of your code and ask an specific question. You cant expect to as to the community: In my job ask me for this. How can I do it? :). Cheers mate.

Comment: eliasMP@ i dont know how stackoverflow works .

Comment: Hi @mohammed You can check the links below: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/
   http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and StackOverflow forum: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: ok i will learn to ask a question by reading the links you provided thank you so much..but as of now can you please give me a valid answer

Comment: As I already explained (and you put link to my answer) Android SDK only allow to verify current user against user of device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android fingerprint API for time attendance app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468694/android-fingerprint-api-for-time-attendance-app)

Comment: You can't _"get users fingerprint"_. You can find out whether the user's fingerprint matches one of the enrolled fingerprints on the device (not which one), and assuming that there was a match you'll have authenticated the use of a `CryptoObject` to perform some cryptographic operation (such as encrypting, decrypting, or signing data).

Comment: @LaurentY thank you so much for editing the question and putting some light on the topic. When i go thorugh answers in stackoverflow i dont see who has answered the question. Thats why i dint know that it was you. THANKS AGAIN

Comment: Refer this link it may help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30365246/9404855)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution my self. Turns out that Bio-metric devices provide an encrypted data when the finger print is read by the them. I think due to security reasons the normal finger print sensor present in the phone don't provide this encrypted data. The closest thing a developer can do with the fingerprint sensor is to find out if the fingerprint matches with the already registered fingerprint in the android device. Because of this i had to use a third party sdk.